# Combinatorics question about picking a staff

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is the Question :

In a building there are 5 men and 5 women. we need to pick representive for the building so that at least one woman and at least one man has to be there. there are no limitions for the size of this staff (between 2 to 10 of course).
In how many ways you can choose this staff ?

Im thinking about picking 1 from the women so its 5 choose 1, the same with the men so again
5 choose 1, and then i dont care if they'll be there or not so its 2^8. 
I've been told it's not the answer but it seems so right and i have no idea why it's wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use principle of inclusion-exclusion:

Let:

$T$ be the set of all possible selections (subsets of the $10$ people);

$G$ be the set of good selections;

$A$ be the set of selections with no men;

$B$ be the set of selections with no women.

Then $|G|=|T|-|A\cup B|=|T|-|A|-|B|+|A\cap B|$

Try to finish from here.

Comment: Seeing rbm's answer working out to $961$, I notice that $961=31^2$, which suggests that an easy way to do this problem is: pick a nonempty subset of women (31 ways) and a nonempty subset of men (31 ways).

Answer (score 4):

There are $2^{10}-1$ all possible combinations. You need to exclude the ones with no male/no female representative. There are 5 ways of choosing an 1 person from 5 people, 10 ways of choosing 2 persons from 5 people etc, so together

$5+10+10+5+1=31$ combinations of choosing 1,2,..,5 persons from 5. This needs to be doubled (exclude female-only *and* male-only combinations), hence the total number is

$2^{10} -1 - 2\times31 = 961$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of how many bad cases you have.

Say $(a,b)$ is $a$ man and $b$ women.
Then all the pairs are OK exept the ones which are $(0,b)$ or $(a,0)$.
Then you have 
$$2\cdot 2^5-1$$
bad cases.